# How to get time from timePicker in another class?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, timepicker

```
public class TimePickerClass  extends Activity{

public TimePicker mTimePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_picker_class);
Button saveTimeButton;
mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
saveTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
saveTimeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    getTime();
});

  public String getTime(){
//TODO
int hour;
int minute;
hour = mTimePicker.getHour();
minute = mTimePicker.getMinute();
String message;
message = "Time:" + hour +" : " + minute;
return message;
}
```

Hello! I have a class in which using TimePicker I get the time chosen by the user. I'm trying to do this:

```
TimePickerClass time = new TimePickerClass();
String userTime = time.getTime();
```

But this does not work, the application is down. How then can this be realized? The error is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.gfc.glanceclock, PID: 32256
          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TimePicker.getHour()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: It seems as though your call to `mTimePicker.getHour()` is causing the null pointer exception.  But, I might not expect this to be possible, assuming `R.id.timePicker` exists in your view.  Does it exist there?

Comment: make a setter and getter of the following  timePicker and pass the instance  to another class and used accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create activity by yourself, that's why necessary lifecycle methods are not called and you get `NullPointerException`.

If you want to get time back from your TimePickerClass activity start it for result, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimePickerClass.class)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

and the set result in your TimePickerClass activity:

```
mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra("time", time.getTime());
                 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                 finish();
            }
        });
```

then you can handle result in

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

method.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: Thank you! I dont know about this! Great!

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use `setOnTimeChangedListener()` to achieve this:-

As you are trying to call the timer methods by using `button` click event it's get `NullPointerException` for the timer.

```
mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                 getTime();
            }
        });
```